# TypeError with tfjs tflite on ReactJS app

Tags: typescript, typeerror, tensorflow.js, tflite

I am trying to load a tflite model into my React app. This is the [repo](https://github.com/ASLGame/ASL-Frontend)

The code that loads the tflite model is inside [here](https://github.com/ASLGame/ASL-Frontend/blob/main/src/components/ModelCamera/components/model.ts)

For some reason, when any of the game pages are loaded, this error appears:
[image]

If I ignore this error, the appplication actually runs just fine. Here is the [website](https://signy-hands.herokuapp.com/) that actually works just find deployed. But I was updating the application by deleting the node_modules and then running `npm install` and now the error in the image above started to show up. I have researched and found [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/6026). It mentions using a different SetWasmPath but that still does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to arise from using the tfjs-tflite library. When I remove the piece of code that is in charge of loading the tflite model it solves the problem.

The question is now, however, how to use a tflite model in a react app.